# Code first one-to-many relationship with restraints

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have the following one-to-many database structure generated by code first.  Many Buttons can be added with a relation back to a single GSMUnit. BtnNo should be unique (for every GSMUnitId), and shouldn't be duplicated. Currently it is possible to duplicate. how can i prevent this?

```
  public class GSMUnit
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Model { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string GsmName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string TelephoneNum { get; set; }
        public int GSMSiteId { get; set; }
        public virtual GSMSite GSMSite { get; set; }
        public virtual GSMSetting GSMSettings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
  }

  public class Button
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Primary { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert3 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string AptNo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4)]
        public string DTO { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4)]
        public string Timeband { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string BtnNo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string AptName { get; set; }
        public int GSMUnitId { get; set; }
        public virtual GSMUnit GSMUnit { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use [HasIndex ()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) directly to make the BtnNo of each Button unique ?

Comment: I tried this but it makes the BtnNo completely unique. I need to be able to add for example which i cant with your suggestion (GSMunitId = 40, BtnNo = 1), (GSMunitId = 64, BtnNo = 1).  What i dont want to happen is (GSMunitId = 40, BtnNo = 1), (GSMunitId = 40, BtnNo = 1)

Comment: Resolved this by using BtnNo and GSMUnitId within the same HasIndex relationship

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Index` attribute for that:

```
  public class Button
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Primary { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Divert3 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string AptNo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4)]
        public string DTO { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4)]
        public string Timeband { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string BtnNo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string AptName { get; set; }

        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public int GSMUnitId { get; set; }
        public virtual GSMUnit GSMUnit { get; set; }
  }
```

But I recommend you to take a look on [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN#PropertyIndex). It's easier to configure in my opinion.